# sudoers for specific command

Tags: 12.04, sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. I want a script to be able to run "ip link blah blah...".

```
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

works as intended, but

```
./myscript.sh
```

gets me : RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted

I have these lines in my sodoers file:

```
myusername ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%mygroup ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/ip, /bin/ip
```

There are no lines following this except a timeout for the timestamp, and the default reference to /etc/sudoers.d

/etc/sudoers.d is empty except for the default README file.

NOPASSWD does not seem to be working either. I have tried moving the lines around so that the timeout and sudoers.d lines are before the ones I mostly care about, with no effect.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /etc/sudoers file only applies to `sudo`. That means that if you do not run programs with `sudo`, it will not get a chance to get elevated privileges. You must use `sudo ./myscript.sh` or edit the script and change something like:

```
ip link ...
```

to:

```
sudo ip link ...
```

Comment: Duh, of course. I knew it would be something simple... Thanks!